# Collision detection with sensor not working in specific case

Tags: python, game-engine, parent, collision, rigidbody

Problem:

- I am encountering an issue with collision detection in Blender Game Engine while working with parented hitboxes. I am using the latest version of BGE on Windows 10.

Details:

1. Hitbox Configuration:

   - Both hitboxes are parented to other objects.
   - The hitboxes have simpler geometry for efficient collision calculations.
   - Rigid Body physics are applied to both hitboxes with Actor on and Ghost off.
   - Collision Bounds are set to Triangle Mesh with a Margin of 0.
   - Scale of both hitboxes is reset to 1.
2. What i've tried:

   - When driving one hitbox into the other, the collision sensors of both hitboxes do not trigger the attached Python program as a Python controller.
   - I've experimented with various configurations, including one hitbox as static with the other as a rigid body, vice versa, and both as static objects.
   - Tried with Collision Bounds on or off, but the issue persists.
   - Adjusted Collision Sensor settings, including Pulse on/off, Pulse true level on/off.
   - The strange observation is that it works with another object (rigid body) falling onto the non-controlled hitbox, which doesn't have any parents.
3. Parenting and Possible Issues:

   - The hitboxes need to be parented to the objects that resemble them, so they keep moving with it
   - It is possible that the parenting might be the issue here.

Am i forgetting something, can someone help me?